# Angular8 webapp not opening in Firefox, Safari

Tags: angular, firefox, safari, cross-browser, angular-cli

I am trying to run my Angular(v8.0.1) Application in Mozilla Firefox v111.0.1 and Safari 5.0.1 but it is not loading the pages however when I try to open this application in Chrome v111.0.55563.147 it is working perfectly.

In console of Mozilla I can see 3 errors in localhost environment:

1. Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://localhost:44316/AppyHealthWeb/.      aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js:234:24
2. Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://localhost:44368/sockjs-node/995/21kq5mab/websocket.     sockjs.js:1684
3. The connection to wss://localhost:44368/sockjs-node/995/21kq5mab/websocket was interrupted while the page was loading.          sockjs.js:1684

ScreenshotLocalURL:

[image: LocalMachine Browser console]

ScreensotDevlopmentURL:

In development and production environment there is no error in browser console except 1 log and 2 warnings:

[image: DevelopmentEnv Browser Console]

Any help you could provide would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems strange that you have some aspdotnet errors whilst working on a Angular Typescript project. Perhaps VS is frustrating your setup? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1007447/what-is-aspnetcore-browser-refresh-js-and-how-can. 
Are you using the Live-server from VS for hot-reload? This is already built-in in Angular development server when starting `ng serve`